# 3G web browsing problems despite full bars

Tags: browser, connection-issues, data-connection, 3g

I consistently have problems browsing the web via my 3G connections despite the fact that it shows that I've got a "good" signal. Often I will have the blue bars but they eventually turn grey after the connection fails. If I keep hitting retry on Chrome it will eventually load the page.

Does anyone have any ideas on what is going on here? Is my carrier doing something strange?

[image]
[image]

(This is on a Galaxy Nexus running Jelly Bean, build number JWR66Y, baseband I9250XXLJ1)

Answer (score 0):

Check the access points(Settings>More>Mobile Network>Access Points) that you have set. In most cases, people have trouble because of the APs they have chosen. Also, try using another SIM card of a different carrier in 3G mode. If all goes well we will know your own phone isn't at fault.